# hybrid gem "freeze" in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i have limited access to my host all i can do is request them the gems that requires native compilation, and the rest, i bundled it in my rails 3.1 application.

i.e Rails 3.1 needs therubyracer, bcrypt-ruby gems, so i requested my host to install this for me, and the rest of the gems are is bundled in my app.

i am trying all sorts of things like removing the things that requires native compilation in Gemfile and Gemfile.lock and rest be bundled in vendor/bundle, but i can't get my application to work.

does bundler has a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can package all gems that are specified inside the Gemfile with the command
`bundle package`. More information can be found on Bundler's website at http://gembundler.com/

Comment: yes i did that, but still gems that requires native compilation throws error in my host since i don't have any sudo access to their server. :(

Comment: marking it as an answer, i just negotiated to my host to have them install my packaged gems.